# Normal MTB trigger shifters and hydraulic brake levers on a bullhorn handlebar

Tags: mountain-bike, shifter, handlebars, brake-levers, bullhorn

Was wondering if mounting Altus shifters and hydraulic brake levers on the vertical sides of a bullhorn handlebar would work or would be possible? I tried holding one of my grips on my flat bar while standing besides my bike as to somewhat recreate the vertical orientation of the bullhorn bars and it seemed to me very possible and accessible. I can imagine my hand position and orientation being similar to as if I was holding or using an exaggerated version of old granny handlebars which can also use normal brake levers and shifters despite the almost vertical-like position of its ends. What are your takes on this? And do you think it will work?

Comment: One more potential compatibility issue: larger grip clamp diameter of the handlebar and smaller one of shifters' clamps. MTB parts are designed around handlebars which taper to 22.2 mm at the ends, while road handlebars and brifters use 23.8 mm. You should measure/learn diameter of your bullhorn handlebar at the place where you intend to clamp the shifters/brakes. See Table 2 at https://bike.bikegremlin.com/3784/bicycle-handlebar-dimension-standards/ or https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-handlebars.html

Comment: I have actually found a bullhorn suited for the diameter of my shifters and levers, and also 31.8 clamping size for my stem

Comment: The hand position may work well, but you will probably find some problems routing the cables neatly (or need very long lengths) as the shifters and brakes are designed with a specific orientation in mind, which is about 90 degrees away from your proposed fitment.

Comment: Wait, what's vertical on a bullhorn bar?  Do you mean mounting the lever vertically on the horizonal portion? When I think of bullhorns, I think of something that's 90% perfectly horizontal, e.g., https://lfgss.microco.sm/api/v1/files/976ad02540b7d4d55ba69fc1549ff5807c85cea3.JPG

Comment: I meant mounting them on the sides. The 2 sides that poiny forward hahaha. Those are what i meant about "vertical" since they deviate from the horizontal side to side path of the main bar.